# doubleLinkedList copy constructor

Tags: linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I'm having trouble implementing a copy constructor for a doubly-linked list. Would I set the tail and previous pointers in the for loop below? The following works for a singly linked list:

```
sortedList::sortedList(const sortedList& original)
: size(original.size)
{
if (original.head == NULL)
    head = NULL;  // original list is empty

else
{
    // copy first node
    head = new listNode;
    tail = new listNode;
    assert(head != NULL);  // check allocation
    assert(tail != NULL);  // check allocation
    head->item = original.head->item;
    tail->item = original.tail->item;
    // copy rest of list
    listNode *newPtr = head;  // new list pointer


    // newPtr points to last node in new list
    // origPtr points to nodes in original list
    for (listNode *origPtr = original.head->next; origPtr != NULL; origPtr = origPtr->next)
    {
         newPtr->next = new listNode;
         assert(newPtr->next != NULL);

         newPtr = newPtr->next;

         newPtr->item = origPtr->item;
        /*
        newPtr = new listNode;
        newPtr->item = origPtr->item;
        newPtr->prev = origPtr->prev;
        tail->next = origPtr;
        tail = origPtr;*/
    }

    newPtr->next = NULL;
}

}
```

Comment: added answer. try to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the prev pointers for every element you copy, inside the loop. Once done, update `head->prev` and `tail->next`.

This might help:

```
 for (listNode *origPtr = original.head->next; origPtr != original.head; origPtr = origPtr->next)
    {
         newPtr->next = new listNode;
         assert(newPtr->next != NULL);

         listNode * prev = newPtr;
         newPtr = newPtr->next;

         newPtr->item = origPtr->item;
         newPtr->prev = prev;
    }

    tail->next = head;
    head->prev = tail;
```